# Programmatically managing Cassandra permissions

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, cassandra

I'm wondering about the best way to manage multitenancy in Cassandra. I have a web app, and I want all users in the web app to have a namespaced area in Cassandra. I can do this via cqlsh (create user with password + grants), but I can't find documentation on it for the ruby, python, or javascript drivers. Any help?

EDIT:

Right now, I'm using the ruby driver and just using `session.execute` but this seems suboptimal for security reasons.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. If you can create users in cqlsh then you can create them in other drivers. They are just cql statements like any other cql statement.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you tried this approach, add tenant info with all your table keys, this way you write your class method to prepare query with tenant will append to it.

1) "ClientA:Name" ....
2) "ClientB:Name"...